# Do items refurbished with ore count towards feng shui?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I've used emerald on a lot of things assuming it then counts as **green** according to Feng Shui and I am wondering if I'm getting points for my efforts or should I just sell the ore instead, because I know that opens up a lot of opportunities towards getting points with furniture that originally was not green or red. Does anyone have any reliable sources/answers?

Comment: Feng Shui always reminds me of Bad Boys 2.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCjbkORhw84

Answer (score 1):

Ores count as colors! (Sapphire - blue, Ruby - red, Emerald - green, etc.) They do count towards Feng Shui as they all count as individual colors.

Comment: Evidence? Where did you get the information to this answer? These questions should be kept in mind while trying to create the perfect answer to inform everyone!

Comment: It doesn't seem to answer the question, which is clearly about furniture refurbished with ore than the ores themselves.

Comment: @Scribblenautical This does answer the question. If you feel it does not maybe you should have the OP clarify his question in bold. Because to me it sounds like he's asking if furniture whose color was change with ore count towards points for Feng Shui. And if you read my answer it says that they do. My source comes from actually testing it in game.

Comment: I never said that you didn't answer the question? @Shelby115 you mean George? Add pictures for more credibility and **maybe** a source online. But no worries! I +1'd the answer because it's a great start!

Comment: @Scribblenautical Oh, my bad. I read them as one comment lol.